# DC current limiter

Tags: power-supply, power, current-source

I have a Velleman amplifier kit which I want to use in a portable manner with an MP3 player. The power input required is specified as 6-14v dc/1A.I intend to use a pp3 battery as a supply, but I have just tested one to find its current output and am getting a reading of 2.5A across its terminals. From a bit of research online it appears I could make a current limiter from a couple of transistors and resistors. I do however not have the electronics background that would enable me to calculate a viable circuit. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: You don't need to limit the current. Current is limited automatically by the load. If the load needs 1A, it'll draw 1A; what you saw was the current it outputs when short-circuited. Now, it should be noted that PP3 batteries typically are rated for about 500mAh, which means you'll only get a half hour of use out of one at 1A. Probably not the best choice here.

Comment: How did you get/measured 2.5A across its terminals?

Answer (score 3):

> The power input required is specified as 6-14v dc/1A.I intend to use a pp3 battery as a supply, ...

A PP3 can not provide enough power.

> but I have just tested one to find its current output and am getting a reading of 2.5A across its terminals.

You have short circuited the battery through your ammeter. Fortunately for you the PP3 doesn't have enough power to supply much current into a short circuit. If you try this with a bigger battery you will destroy your meter. If you try it with a really big one you could experience arc flash and risk injury or death.

What you have demonstrated is that the battery provides 2.5 A into a short circuit with 0 V across the load (the short). This means that the battery has an internal resistance of \$ \frac {V}{I} = \frac {9}{2.5} = 3.6 \ \Omega \$.

You are intending to run your circuit at 9 V rather than 0 V so this reading doesn't help you much.

> From a bit of research online it appears I could make a current limiter from a couple of transistors and resistors.

If it is a 9 V circuit then you just connect it to the battery. The circuit will draw the current it requires - if the battery is capable.

---

A random decent looking 9 V battery with a datasheet, the [Ultralife U9VL-J-P](https://cellpacksolutions.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/ultralife-u9vl-jp-technical-data-sheet.pdf) is rated at 150 mA continuous.

[image]

- Note that the voltage can drop significantly in their tests.
- Nominal capacity is 1.2 Ah. That means that if you draw the recommended 0.15 A continuous max current that it will last for \$ \frac {1.2}{0.15} = 8\ \text h \$.